# layer index and the opacity issue

Tags: html, css, opacity, transparent

i set the opacity property of the outer div to the .5,
and i set the inner div's opacity value to be 1 
but it still to be transparent at all

here is the sample code:
**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
            <div id="div3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1{
        background: black;
        opacity:.5;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        }
        #div2{
            background:white;
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        #div3{
            display: block;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            opacity: 1;
            background: black;
        }
```

so where is the problem?
or anything i have miss ? 
help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common misconception about CSS, you can't set opacity on a parent and then prevent it from affecting its children. What you need is to set an alpha color for `#div1`:

```
#div1{
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i shall really have misunderstood this before.and the rgba does not work in IE ,so i should get a png file to get IE done ?

Comment: Yes, I very much prefer semitransparent PNGs because they are tested and reliable. But if you'd like more code flexibility see http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/

Comment: +1 for the link and I think you should include it in your answer!!! I can't believe I have never seen that. My answer is officially retracted!

Comment: Also, here is a working sample for @strangeline based on the solution in your link above (it uses IE8 hacks...I know...shame on me): http://jsfiddle.net/97xLM/

Comment: Thank you all,this is far more good for a one new to Web Development!really really thank you ! all these are so useful !